# How to forward next step after schema validation

Tags: xml, xsd, mule

I am validating an XML with XSD using schema validation. 
While running in debugging mode it is unable to continue after schema validation. 
I past the snippet below.

```
<flow name="xmlwithxsdofdbFlow">
  <poll doc:name="Poll">
    <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10000"/>
    <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
      <db:parameterized-query>
        <![CDATA[select * from tblcustomer where batch='N';]]>
      </db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
  </poll>
  <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map
{
    id : $.Id,
    customerid : $.Customerid,
    address : $.Address,
    dob : $.Dob,
    firstname : $.Firstname,
    lastname : $.LastName,
    middlename : $.Middlename,
    phoneno : $.Phoneno,
    batch : $.Batch,
    recorddate : $.RecordDate

}]]>
    </dw:set-payload>
  </dw:transform-message>
  <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
  <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  <mulexml:schema-validation-filter
      schemaLocations="customer_validation.xsd"
      returnResult="false" doc:name="Schema Validation"/>
  <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

This is Xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on -->
  <!-- Fri Sep 02 2016 15:02:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) -->
  <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
  <xs:element name="Customer_schema_validation">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="CustomerData" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Customerid" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" nillable="false"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Dob" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Firstname" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Middlename" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Phoneno" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Batch" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="RecordDate" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: May be you forgot to paste snippet. Also your question isn't clear?

Comment: Now the xml flow is available. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for update. You can also share the customer_validation.xsd. Before that you dont need to you object-to-xml-transformer just change this in dataweave. '%output application/xml'

Comment: I am getting payload as like this com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler@85c353c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml generated from your code isn't valid. You have to change your dataweave script. This is working fine for me

```
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="customer_validation.xsd" returnResult="false" name="Schema_Validation"
        doc:name="Schema Validation" />

    <flow name="testFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="tmp" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="aef6cf8e-4db2-4e6e-9838-81f7aedff827" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    Customer_schema_validation: {
        (payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
            CustomerData: {
                Id: payload01.Id,
                Customerid: payload01.Customerid,
                Address: payload01.Address,
                Dob: payload01.Dob,
                Firstname: payload01.Firstname,
                LastName: payload01.LastName,
                Middlename: payload01.Middlename,
                Phoneno: payload01.Phoneno,
                Batch: payload01.Batch,
                RecordDate: payload01.RecordDate
            }
        }))
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <message-filter onUnaccepted="error_invalid_data" doc:name="Message">
            <mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="customer_validation.xsd" returnResult="false"/>
        </message-filter>

  <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    </flow>

    <flow name="error_invalid_data" >
        <logger message="ERROR: MESSAGE PAYLOAD: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
```

This is routing messge to error flow when generated file not valid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @6340408 , Also tested with your code.. Its working fine. when proper xml is generated. Just use the dataweave mentioned in answer.

Comment: Thanks anupam, It's working fine. But In my scenario I am getting data from db, in that address field may be null or value. I converted as xml format then its map with xsd. In xsd address column given as nillbale=false. Whenever I get the address is null need to raise an exception. I am already put the data without null in address, i tried to run the flow as per your suggestion, but it's going to error_invalid_data flow. How can i fix please suggest me.

Comment: if you want to pass put condition in dataweave to check for null and replace with bank.like `Address: payload01.Address when payload01.Address != null otherwise "" `